# Generate Sign Apk in Android Studio v 4.0.1 after loosing the key of the app

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

I have little experience in publishing apps and I am here for some help, since I don't know how to solve my issue.
So I am working with a colleague on an app and since a couple of weeks, we can't update it - we get an error of SHA certificate which apparently aren't the same (of the original and the latest version). So we've contacted the Google support and we have been told to rename the package and to change the key.
My colleague and I are having some doubts, even more after reading the documentation:

1. The first thing we should do is to get our debug keystore by running the cmd in the terminal

   - 1a - First doubt: Do we need even the release keystore for publishing the app?
   - 1b - Second doubt: If we have the project in Firebase and we add to the project a new app with a different package name and we download the latest google-services.json, does this need to have inside both debug and release keystores of both devs?
2. How can I generate the signed APK ready to be published? I have Android Studio v4.0.1 and I can't find a way to get the signed APK. And in all the docs I've read so far, they suggest to use Build-->Build-->Generate Sign APK, and this is not appearing in the version I am working on.
3. What does the google-services.json, the debug keystore and the release exactly do? Is everything necessary for the publishing of an app?
4. How can a dev avoid to lose the key? Are there any best practices?

If it's necessary I can publish the build.gradle of both the project and the app or take screenshots. Sorry in advance for some "misleading" or "confused" parts of my question.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

to recover your password in this path:

```
C:\Users\yourUser\.Android2.2\system\log\idea.log.1
```

**NOTE:** if you not get password then read this doucmentation:

```
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing
```